# How to write my own code in NetSim?

Tags: c, networking, simulation, simulator

I want to write my own custom code for Simulation in NetSim of www.tetcos.com. 
I am a newbie to NetSim and can anyone explain me how to create new project ?  Or just how do I printf to NetSim console ? Like a basic hello world type project ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are three simple steps on how to start customization of code:

Step 1: Set up your project: Set your compiler such that your project code compiles into a Dynamic Link Library (DLL) in win (or Dynamic Shared Library (.so) in Linux).

Step 2: Copy source code: NetSim’s installation directory contains the source code for all protocols in folder $(NETSIM_INSTALL_DIR)/NetSim/Simulation/src . Copy paste the following files:
a. Header files related to TCP from the path $(NETSIM_INSTALL_DIR)/src/simulation/include
b. Lib files related to TCP from the path $(NETSIM_INSTALL_DIR)/src/simulation/lib 
c. Source files related to TCP from the path $(NETSIM_INSTALL_DIR)/src/Simulation/tcp

Step 3: Modify code and replace the binary: Open TCP.c and write the Hello World print statement just after the TCP init function. Then build your code and replace the existing binary of NetSim (libTCP.dll or libTCP.so(for linux) in $(NETSIM_INSTALL_DIR)/NetSim/Simulation/bin) with your libTCP.dll(or libTCP.so).

Next, run a simulation you would see "Hello World" in command line.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I followed the steps you mentioned and the dll file got built. I then replaced it in the ..NetSim Standard/bin folder and ran. The simulation ran fine but I did not see the "Hello World" in the console. I am sure it was my dll because I removed the original dll and placed it else where. So I know it is running my code, but I am not able to see the hello world with printf. Please assist.

Comment: @user3701620 In NetSim, printf has been redirected to write on the file(%temp% folder) not stdout but if you want to see your output on console/Terminal, you can use fprintf function and change your output stream to stderr (use stderr for FILE* arguments in fprintf)

Comment: Just wanted to inform that this has changed as of NetSim v11.1 with the introduction of workspaces. There is not need to replace DLL etc. Just open code, build and run